# Multiple operations iterating over dataframe columns (apply function?)

Tags: pandas, function, dataframe, iteration, apply

I have a pandas dataframe with thousands of columns and I would like to perform the following operations for each column of the dataframe:

1. check if the value `i`-th and `i-1`-th values are in the range (between `x` and `y`);
2. if #1 is satisfied, then find `log(i/i-1) ** 2` of the column;
3. if #1 is not satisfied, assume 0;
4. find the total of #2 for each column.

Here is a dataframe with a single column:

```
d = {'col1': [10, 15, 23, 16, 5, 14, 11, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df
```

`x = 10` and `y = 20`

Here is what I can do for this single column:

```
df["IsIn"] = "NA" 
for i in range(1, len(df.col1)):
    if (x < df.col1[i] < y) & (x < df.col1[i - 1] < y):
        df.IsIn[i] = 1
    else:
        df.IsIn[i] = 0

df["rets"] = np.log(df["col1"] / df["col1"].shift(1))
df["var"] = df["IsIn"] * df["rets"]**2
Total = df["var"].sum()
Total
```

Ideally, I would have a (1 by n-cols) dataframe of `Totals` for each column. How can I best achieve this? I would also appreciate if you can supplement your answer with detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is an instance where `apply` works. You only need to wrap your logic in a function. Also, consider `between` and `shift` on the condition to eliminate the first loop:

```
def func(s, x=10, y=20):
    '''
    compute the value given a series
    ''' 

    # mask where values are between x and y
    valid = s.between(x,y)

    # shift `valid` and double check
    valid = valid & valid.shift(fill_value=False)

    # squared log, mask with `valid`, and sum
    return (np.log(s/s.shift())**2 * valid).sum()

# apply `func` on the columns
df.apply(func, x=10, y=20)
```

Output:

```
col1    0.222561
dtype: float64
```